# Composer already installed but when i want to create a new project using cmd in laravel below error found

Tags: laravel, cmd, composer-php, new-project

```
c:\wamp\www\hotels>composer create -project --prefer -dist laravel hotel "5.8.*"

[RuntimeException]
Invalid working directory specified, ist does not exist.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your command is not correct to install `Laravel`

**Change**

```
composer create -project --prefer -dist laravel hotel "5.8.*"
```

**to**

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel hotel "5.8.*"
```

Reference:

[Laravel -> Installing Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x#installing-laravel)